# switch in calculator app objective-c not running

Tags: objective-c, switch-statement, calculator

I'm working on a calculator app (code below) that takes values through a UITextField, stores them to an array (varArray) when an operand button is pushed.  Pushing an operand button also stores that operand in another array (opArray) and clears varTextField.  Pushing the equal button (which is not yet fully implemented, still trying to get to values and an operand calculated before I move on) will execute the calculation and display it in a label (equationLabel).  All of this is to provide multi-variable functionality.  In the end I want to be able to enter something like: var1, op1, var2, op2, var3...etc., and have the entire equation/result displayed in equationLabel.

I've also equated the operands to int values for the switch.

I'm stuck at the moment because the switch that combines the variables and operands doesn't seem to be running at all.  The result item is sent to equationLabel, but only with the default value 0.

I'm relatively new to coding, and more so to objective-c, so I might just be doing something stupid here.  Any help would with the switch issue would be greatly appreciated.

I should also mention that on each of the switch cases, I get the following warning from xCode: "Local declaration of 'result' hides instance variable.

**updated code2**
Works perfectly, except that the app doesn't seem to write to the arrays in opButtonPush until the equalButton is pushed for the first time.  The array values return as null until that UI event.

```
- (IBAction)opButtonPush:(id)sender    //if +, -, /, or x buttons are pushed, add value in varTextField to varArray and button label text to setOpArray
{    
     UIButton *tmpButton = (UIButton *)sender;

     float textValue=0;

     //add operand to opArray to be accessed by displayEquation and calculator then added to equationLabel and calcFunction
    if ([[[tmpButton titleLabel] text] isEqualToString:@"+"])
    {
        textValue = [[varTextField text] floatValue];
        [opArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]];
        [varOpArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:textValue]];
        [varOpArray addObject:@"+"];
        [varArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:textValue]];
        varTextField.text = @"";
    }
    else if ([[[tmpButton titleLabel] text] isEqualToString:@"-"])
    {
        textValue = [[varTextField text] floatValue];
        [opArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];
        [varOpArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:textValue]];
        [varOpArray addObject:@"-"];
        [varArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:textValue]];
        varTextField.text = @"";
    }
    else if ([[[tmpButton titleLabel] text] isEqualToString:@"x"])
    {
        textValue = [[varTextField text] floatValue];
        [opArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2]];
        [varOpArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:textValue]];
        [varOpArray addObject:@"x"];
        [varArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:textValue]];
        varTextField.text = @"";
    }
    else if ([[[tmpButton titleLabel] text] isEqualToString:@"/"])
    {
        textValue = [[varTextField text] floatValue];
        [opArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:3]];
        [varOpArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:textValue]];
        [varOpArray addObject:@"/"];
        [varArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:textValue]];
        varTextField.text = @"";
    }
    else if ([[[tmpButton titleLabel] text] isEqualToString:@"+/-"])
    {
        [varTextField setText:@"-"];
    }

    [equationLabel setText:[varOpArray description]];   //send vars and ops, as entered, to equationLabel

    //NSLog(@"%@", varOpArray);
}

- (IBAction)calculator:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *tmpButton = (UIButton *)sender;

    int opCount=0;

    float finalTextValue=0;
    float result = [[varArray objectAtIndex:0] floatValue];

    if ([[[tmpButton titleLabel] text] isEqualToString:@"="]) {
        finalTextValue = [[varTextField text] floatValue];
        [varArray addObject:[varTextField text]];
        [varOpArray addObject:[varTextField text]];
        [varOpArray addObject:@"="];
        [equationLabel setText:[varOpArray description]];

        for (int i=1; i<[varArray count]; i++) {     //use opArray[i] to eval the result and new var
                                                  //then write it to an array
            switch ([[opArray objectAtIndex:opCount] intValue]) {
                case 0:
                    result = result + [[varArray objectAtIndex:(i)] floatValue];
                    [resultArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:result]];
                    [equationLabel setText:[varOpArray description]];   //send vars and ops, as entered, to equationLabel
                    break;
                case 1:
                    result = result - [[varArray objectAtIndex:(i)] floatValue];
                    [resultArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:result]];
                    [equationLabel setText:[varOpArray description]];   //send vars and ops, as entered, to equationLabel
                    break;
                case 2:
                    result = result * [[varArray objectAtIndex:(i)] floatValue];
                    [resultArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:result]];
                    [equationLabel setText:[varOpArray description]];   //send vars and ops, as entered, to equationLabel
                    break;
                case 3:
                    result = result / [[varArray objectAtIndex:(i)] floatValue];
                    [resultArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:result]];
                    [equationLabel setText:[varOpArray description]];   //send vars and ops, as entered, to equationLabel
                    break;
                default:
                    NSLog(@"default");
                    break;
            }
            opCount++;
        }
        [varOpArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:result]];
        [equationLabel setText:[varOpArray description]];

        [varTextField setText:@""];

        //reset arrays for next function 
        varOpArray = [NSMutableArray new];
        varArray = [NSMutableArray new];
        opArray = [NSMutableArray new];
    }
}
```

**updated code1:**

```
- (IBAction)opButtonPush:(id)sender    //if +, -, /, or x buttons are pushed, add value in varTextField to varArray and button label text to setOpArray
{    
    UIButton *tmpButton = (UIButton *)sender;

    float textValue=0;

    //add operand to opArray to be accessed by displayEquation and calculator then added to equationLabel and calcFunction
    if ([[[tmpButton titleLabel] text] isEqualToString:@"+"])
    {
        textValue = [[varTextField text] floatValue];
        [opArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]];
        [varOpArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:textValue]];
        [varOpArray addObject:@"+"];
        [varArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:textValue]];
    }
    else if ([[[tmpButton titleLabel] text] isEqualToString:@"-"])
    {
        textValue = [[varTextField text] floatValue];
        [opArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];
        [varOpArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:textValue]];
        [varOpArray addObject:@"-"];
        [varArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:textValue]];
    }
    else if ([[[tmpButton titleLabel] text] isEqualToString:@"x"])
    {
        textValue = [[varTextField text] floatValue];
        [opArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2]];
        [varOpArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:textValue]];
        [varOpArray addObject:@"x"];
        [varArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:textValue]];
    }
    else if ([[[tmpButton titleLabel] text] isEqualToString:@"/"])
    {
        textValue = [[varTextField text] floatValue];
        [opArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:3]];
        [varOpArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:textValue]];
        [varOpArray addObject:@"/"];
        [varArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:textValue]];
    }

    //add value of float var to arrays to be accessed by calculator 

    [equationLabel setText:[varOpArray description]];   //send vars and ops, as entered, to equationLabel

    varTextField.text = @"";
    NSLog(@"%@", varOpArray);

}

- (IBAction)calculator:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *tmpButton = (UIButton *)sender;

    int opCount=0;

    float finalTextValue=0;
    float result=0.0;

    if ([[[tmpButton titleLabel] text] isEqualToString:@"="]) {
        finalTextValue = [[varTextField text] floatValue];
        //[opArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:4]];
        [varOpArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:finalTextValue]];
        [varOpArray addObject:@"="];
        [varArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:finalTextValue]];

        for (int i=0; i<[varArray count]; i+=2) {            
            switch ([[opArray objectAtIndex:opCount] intValue]) {
                case 0:
                    result = [[varArray objectAtIndex:i] floatValue] + [[varArray objectAtIndex:(i+1)] floatValue];
                    [varOpArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:result]];
                    varTextField.text = @"";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    result = [[varArray objectAtIndex:i] floatValue] - [[varArray objectAtIndex:(i+1)] floatValue];
                    [varOpArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:result]];
                    varTextField.text = @"";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    result = [[varArray objectAtIndex:i] floatValue] * [[varArray objectAtIndex:(i+1)] floatValue];
                    [varOpArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:result]];
                    varTextField.text = @"";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    result = [[varArray objectAtIndex:i] floatValue] / [[varArray objectAtIndex:(i+1)] floatValue];
                    [varOpArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:result]];
                    varTextField.text = @"";
                    break;
                default:
                    NSLog(@"default");
                    break;
            }

            opCount++;
        }
        varOpArray = [NSMutableArray new];
        varArray = [NSMutableArray new];
        opArray = [NSMutableArray new];
        [varTextField resignFirstResponder];
    }

}

- (IBAction)textFieldClear:(id)sender
{
    if ([varTextField isFirstResponder])
    {

    }
    else
    {
        [varTextField becomeFirstResponder];
        varTextField.text = @"";
    }
}
```

**Original Code**

```
- (IBAction)opButtonPush:(id)sender    //if +, -, /, or * buttons are pushed, add value in varTextField to varArray and button label text to setOpArray
{
    UIButton *tmpButton = (UIButton *)sender;

    //add value of float var to varArray to be accessed by displayEquation and calculator then added to equationLabel and calcFunction
    if ([[tmpButton titleLabel] text] != @"=" || [[tmpButton titleLabel] text] != @"+/-") {
        varArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:varTextField.text, nil];
    }

    //add operand to opArray to be accessed by displayEquation and calculator then added to equationLabel and calcFunction

    if ([[[tmpButton titleLabel] text] isEqualToString:@"+"])
    {
        opArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"+", nil];
    }

    else if ([[[tmpButton titleLabel] text] isEqualToString:@"-"])
    {
        opArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"-", nil];
    }

    else if ([[[tmpButton titleLabel] text] isEqualToString:@"x"])
    {
        opArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"*", nil];
    }

    else if ([[[tmpButton titleLabel] text] isEqualToString:@"/"])
    {
        opArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"/", nil];
    }
    varTextField.text = @"";     //clear varTextField
}

- (IBAction)calculator:(id)sender
{
    [equationLabel setText:@"x + y = z"];

    NSString *tmpVar;
    NSString *tmpOp;
    float var;

    int varCount = [varArray count];
    int opCount = [opArray count];

    UIButton *tmpButton = (UIButton *)sender;

    if ([[[tmpButton titleLabel] text] isEqualToString:@"="]) {

        //for each instance of varArray and opArray, add it to the string "equation" and equation label
        for (int i=0; i<[varArray count]; i++) {
            tmpVar = [varArray objectAtIndex:i];
            var = ([tmpVar floatValue]);
            for (int j=0; j<[opArray count]; j++) {
                tmpOp = [opArray objectAtIndex:j];
                //equationLabel = 
            }
        }
    }
    //result =
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `!=` to compare strings in this line:

```
if ([[tmpButton titleLabel] text] != @"=" || [[tmpButton titleLabel] text] != @"+/-") {
```

instead use `isEqualToString`:

```
if (![[[tmpButton titleLabel] text] isEqualToString:@"="] || ![[[tmpButton titleLabel] text] isEqualToString:@"+/-"]) {
```

Your `opArray` contains objects of type `NSString`.  To assign that value to an int, you need to ask the `NSString` for its `intValue`.  You also want to use `objectAtIndex` to retrieve values from your `opArray`.

Since you are using it as the index into the array, then you need to do 2 things:

1) Set `opCount` to `0` **before** the `for` loop.

`opCount = 0;`

2) In your `switch` statement, do the following:

`switch([[opArray objectAtIndex:opCount] intValue]) {`

I still see several problems:

1) Are you sure you're not hitting the switch statement?  Put an `NSLog` immediately before your switch.

2) In an equation such as `1+2*3/4-5=` you really only have one operation per operand and the second operand is the previous result.  Once `=` is detected, I would set `result` to the first value in varArray, then I would start with the second operand in the `for` loop (start your index `i` at `1` and only increment `i` by 1 each time through the loop.  Use the variable `result` as your first operand in all of your calculations.

3) Please leave each version of your code in the question above, otherwise the answers don't make sense to someone who comes along later and reads them.

4) Only after your final result has been calculated do you want to do (that is, after your `for` loop).

```
[varOpArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:result]];
```

Don't forget to display `varOpArray` before clearing it.

5) Apparently you have an instance variable (or property) in your class called `result` which is why you're getting the error message.  Get rid of it and just use the local result you have defined.

This modified code works:

```
- (IBAction)opButtonPush:(id)sender {
    UIButton *tmpButton = (UIButton *)sender;

    float textValue=0;

    //add operand to opArray to be accessed by displayEquation and calculator then added to equationLabel and calcFunction
    if ([[[tmpButton titleLabel] text] isEqualToString:@"+"])
    {
        textValue = [[varTextField text] floatValue];
        [opArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]];
        [varOpArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:textValue]];
        [varOpArray addObject:@"+"];
        [varArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:textValue]];
    }
    else if ([[[tmpButton titleLabel] text] isEqualToString:@"-"])
    {
        textValue = [[varTextField text] floatValue];
        [opArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];
        [varOpArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:textValue]];
        [varOpArray addObject:@"-"];
        [varArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:textValue]];
    }
    else if ([[[tmpButton titleLabel] text] isEqualToString:@"x"])
    {
        textValue = [[varTextField text] floatValue];
        [opArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2]];
        [varOpArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:textValue]];
        [varOpArray addObject:@"x"];
        [varArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:textValue]];
    }
    else if ([[[tmpButton titleLabel] text] isEqualToString:@"/"])
    {
        textValue = [[varTextField text] floatValue];
        [opArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:3]];
        [varOpArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:textValue]];
        [varOpArray addObject:@"/"];
        [varArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:textValue]];
    }

    //add value of float var to arrays to be accessed by calculator 

    [equationLabel setText:[varOpArray description]];   //send vars and ops, as entered, to equationLabel

    varTextField.text = @"";
    NSLog(@"%@", varOpArray);

}

- (IBAction)calculator:(id)sender {
    UIButton *tmpButton = (UIButton *)sender;

    int opCount=0;

    float finalTextValue=0;
    float result=0.0;

    if ([[[tmpButton titleLabel] text] isEqualToString:@"="]) {
        finalTextValue = [[varTextField text] floatValue];
        //[opArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:4]];
        [varOpArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:finalTextValue]];
        [varOpArray addObject:@"="];
        [varArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:finalTextValue]];

        result = [[varArray objectAtIndex:0] floatValue];

        for (int i=1; i<[varArray count]; i++) { 
            NSLog(@"switch hit");
            switch ([[opArray objectAtIndex:opCount] intValue]) {
                case 0:
                    result = result + [[varArray objectAtIndex:i] floatValue];
                    varTextField.text = @"";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    result = result - [[varArray objectAtIndex:i] floatValue];
                    varTextField.text = @"";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    result = result * [[varArray objectAtIndex:i] floatValue];
                    varTextField.text = @"";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    result = result / [[varArray objectAtIndex:i] floatValue];
                    varTextField.text = @"";
                    break;
                default:
                    NSLog(@"default");
                    break;
            }

            opCount++;
        }
        [varOpArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:result]];
        [equationLabel setText:[varOpArray description]];      

        varOpArray = [NSMutableArray new];
        varArray = [NSMutableArray new];
        opArray = [NSMutableArray new];
        [varTextField resignFirstResponder];
    }

}
```

Comment: Since you're new to StackOverflow.  Please select the checkmark under the number next to my answer above if you find this correctly answered your question.

Comment: Thanks!  I was setting up the switch expression all wrong, but there's still something off.  The switch is still being skipped, so I'm guessing the problem is with the if or for statements above it.

Comment: By the way, you can only select one answer as "the answer".

Comment: Thanks again vacawama.  It's funny how putting this sort of project down over night put's everything into perspective.  I turned on my computer about 30 minutes before looking to see if anyone else posted, and began seeing a good bit of what you're talking about.  I can also chalk it up to lack of experience and taking an adviser's pseudo code suggestions too literally.  None are mutually exclusive though...

Sorry for deleting the original code.  I'd put it back up, but I've since over written the file.

I'll run through all of this and post results.

Thanks again for your help.

Comment: ...and you were right about getting to the switch.  I used a NSLog under both the for and switch:case 1 statements, and they registered in the output dialog.

Comment: Found the original Code, and placed it below the 2nd iteration.

Comment: Works perfectly, except that the app doesn't seem to write to the arrays in opButtonPush until the equalButton is pushed for the first time. The array values return as null until that UI event.

Posted latest code above.

Comment: It doesn't work until you press equals for the first time because you are not allocating the arrays until then.  You can implement viewDidLoad and set varArray, opArray, and varOpArray each to [NSMutableArray new] there.

Comment: Right again sir.  I do have to keep them in calculator too though, otherwise varOpArray just keeps growing.  I'm confused on this one though.  I thought these arrays were initialized in the header file.  Wouldn't all of the earlier methods writing to the arrays cause it to break if it hadn't been initialized?

Comment: Objective-C allows you to do things with nil objects without crashing.  It is a feature of the language.  So, calling methods on nil does nothing, but it doesn't crash.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to understand your project.
I may be wrong, but it seems that:
in the for loop, opCount 
should be  objectAtIndex;

and 
result should be =, not +=

Comment: Totally right about objectAtIndex.  Removing the = doesn't change the function at this point since I'm still not getting into the switch.